# Get case-sensitive name of file

Tags: perl, file-rename, case-insensitive

I have a Perl script that needs to work on any platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.).  Part of its functionality is to rename files, but I don't want it to overwrite existing files.  Let's say the script is called "my_rename" and it takes the same arguments as the "rename" function, and the user executes this command:

```
my_rename test.txt test.TXT
```

The problem occurs if `-e "test.txt"` and `-e "test.TXT"` both return true.  Here is how I would like to handle this situation under the following conditions:

Case 1: On a case-sensitive filesystem:

- abort with an error that "test.TXT" exists

Case 2: On a case-insensitive filesytem when the actual case of the existing filename is "test.TXT":

- give a warning that the file name is unchanged

Case 3: On a case-insensitive filesystem when the actual case of the existing filename is NOT "test.TXT":

- rename the file to "test.TXT"

Since this script has to be portable, it can not rely on system-dependent functions or utilities.

Answer (score 6):

What I've done here in the past is to skip `-e` and go straight to `readdir`.

On the input, you need to know how many case-insensitive matches with readdir.

```
if (! -e $input)
{
  die "No such file: $input";
}

my $input_case_insensitive_matches = () = use_readdir_to_find($input);
my $output_is_case_match = use_readdir_to_find($output);

if ($input_case_insensitive_matches > 1 && $output_is_case_match)
{
  # case sensitive filesystem, target exists, as does the input file
  die "$output already exists";
}

if ($output_is_case_match)
{
  # case insensitive filesystem, no change required
  warn "$input is already $output";
}
else
{
  # case can be changed
  rename $input, $output;
}
```

Some debugging is likely required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but you seem to be already assuming that the filesystem is case-insensitive.  I can't make that assumption.  Also, readdir is seriously broken in Windows for file names that contain Unicode characters.

Comment: I don't think I'm making the former assumption, but the unicode side I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Ah.  I see now.  On case-sensitive systems when both files exist, the case-insensitive readdir search will find more than one file.  Got it.   That still leaves the Unicode headache though.

Comment: I was confused because use_readdir_to_find() must be case insensitive when searching for $input, but case sensitive for $output.

Comment: it's using context - return all case-insensitive matches in list context, and the exact case-sensitive match (or nothing) in scalar context. Or use different functions, whatever.

Comment: Ah.  Smart.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip!

Below is my implementation of *use_readdir_to_find()*. I expect it would work as-is only on Windows, but removing the optimization would probably make it work everywhere.

```
=head3 find_file_case_insensitive

 Purpose: Check if a file exists and is not empty, regardless of the case
 Usage  : @files = find_file_case_insensitive($file);
 Returns: in list context: all case-insensitive matches
          in scalar context: the exact case-sensitive match (or nothing)
 Arguments:
   $file: the name of the file to find
 Notes  : Remove the optimization to support case-sensitive systems.

=cut
sub find_file_case_insensitive {
  my ($file) = @_;

  ## Optimization: check if the file exists, regardless of case.
  ## Remove this for case-sensitive operating systems.
  ## Remove the -s flag if looking for empty files as well.
  unless (-r -f -s $file) {
    if (wantarray) {
      return ();
    } else {
      return undef;
    }
  }

  my ($filename, $dir, undef) = fileparse($file);

  my $found_exact;
  my @found_insensitive;
  opendir(my $dh, $dir) || die "Can't opendir $dir: $!";
  while (readdir $dh) {
    $found_exact = $_ if ($_ eq $filename);
    push(@found_insensitive, $_) if (fc($_) eq fc($filename));
  }
  closedir $dh;

  if (wantarray) {
    return @found_insensitive;
  } else {
    return $found_exact;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can lose the first `wantarray` stuff. Use a `return;` (no argument) and you'll get the same thing. So, `return unless -r -f -s $file`.